# USB drive corrupt games?

Tags: xbox-one, hard-drive

So I was gonna play on my Xbox and I clicked a game (which was dying light)
and it said that it was corrupt, so then I uninstalled and tried reinstalling the game but it wouldn’t let me install.... I didn’t know what to do so I tried rainbow 6 siege and apex legends and they didn't work either.

The next day I went on my Xbox again and realized that it was my usb drive, so I transferred all my games on there to my internal storage and the installation worked and now I can play my games without it saying it’s corrupt.

Why isn't my USB working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe the drive wasn't formatted correctly. Even if it was, you may want to do so again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

USB drives, like any other flash drive, can stop working for a multitude of reasons. Without more technical information, your question is too broad and cannot be answered adequately.